# Is allocating 32GB of max heap okay for PhpStorm and extremely large projects?

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm, heap-memory, jetbrains-ide

I have recently switched from VS Code to PhpStorm and I am loving it's extra features like adding try catches, advanced syntax highlighting etc. But this all comes at a cost of memory. I am editing a huge PHP codebase which instantly uses 10GB-12GB of RAM when I open it.

Is there anything wrong with allocating 32GB -Xmx and 16GB -Xms? I have 64GB RAM in my system so I still have plenty of headroom.

[image: max heap, allocated, and used]

[image: VM options]

Comment: PHPStorm can have some issues and performance hits when opening projects, either try EAP version or write a ticket in their youtrack system if you are experiencing problems https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI. If you are on windows excluding project from real time scanning of windows defender also helps.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will try removing it from real time scanning. I always have to fight windows defender when it removed my .pdb and .dll files during compilation of C/C++/Rust.